# Asp.Net Core Razor Pages authorization handlers for policies with Authorize attribute on PageModel still run after executing policies set to folders

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, razor-pages, asp.net-core-identity

I'm creating a simple Asp.Net Core Web App using Razor Pages and Asp.Net Core Identity and I having an issue where the authorization handlers for policies applied to a PageModel are still executed after a policy applied for the same Page's folder despite each authorization handler is related to a different Requirement Class. My problem is that even calling Context.Fail() at the folder policy authorization handler, an unauthenticated user seems to still reach the Page and this fires the Page policy authorization handler then throws an exception because the User object is null. I want to implement a simple Flow where requests to Pages are first validated by the policies set on the Folders they belong to, ok? continue to Page (and run the Page authorization handler), not ok, return a forbidden response immediately.

Any help is really appreciated.

Requirements:

```
public class SectionsAccessRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public string SectionName { get; }

    public SectionsAccessRequirement(string Name)
    {
        SectionName = Name;
    }
}   

public class RecordCreateRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement { }
```

Authorization handlers:

```
public class SectionsAccessHandler : AuthorizationHandler<SectionsAccessRequirement>
{
    public IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

    public SectionsAccessHandler(IHttpContextAccessor Accessor) => _accessor = Accessor;
    
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, SectionsAccessRequirement requirement)
    {
        // Require authentication
        if (!_accessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) context.Fail();

        // Admin
        if (context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimNameConstants.UserGroup && c.Value == UserGroupConstants.AdminGroup)) context.Succeed(requirement);
                                
        if (requirement.SectionName == SectionNameConstants.AdminSection) context.Fail();

        // Client
        if (requirement.SectionName == SectionNameConstants.ClientSection && context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimNameConstants.ClientSection)) context.Succeed(requirement);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class RecordCreateAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<RecordCreateRequirement>
{
    private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _users;

    public RecordCreateAuthorizationHandler(UserManager<AppUser> Users) => _users = Users;

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RecordCreateRequirement requirement)
    {
        // User ID
        int sessionUserId = int.Parse(_users.GetUserId(context.User));

        // Privileges
        if (!context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimNameConstants.UserGroup && c.Value == UserGroupConstants.AdminGroup))
        {
            if (context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimNameConstants.ClientCreate)) context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

I have these two extension methods:

```
public static class AuthorizationOptionsExtension
{
    public static void AddPolicies(this AuthorizationOptions Options)
    {
        // Folders policies
        Options.AddPolicy(PolicyNameConstants.AdminSectionPolicy, p => p.Requirements.Add(new SectionsAccessRequirement(SectionNameConstants.AdminSection)));
        Options.AddPolicy(PolicyNameConstants.ClientSectionPolicy, p => p.Requirements.Add(new SectionsAccessRequirement(SectionNameConstants.ClientSection)));

        // Pages policies
        Options.AddPolicy(PolicyNameConstants.ClientRecordCreatePolicy, p => p.Requirements.Add(new Client.RecordCreateRequirement()));

        // Fallback policy 
        Options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
    }        
}
```

And:

```
public static class RazorPagesOptionsExtension
{
    public static void AddFoldersAuthorization(this RazorPagesOptions Options)
    {
        Options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Admin", PolicyNameConstants.AdminSectionPolicy);

        Options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Client", PolicyNameConstants.ClientSectionPolicy);
    }
}
```

The Page's policy is applied using an Authorize attribute:

```
[Authorize(Policy = PolicyNameConstants.ClientRecordCreatePolicy)]
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{ ... }
```

This is my startup class, I'm using Asp.Net Core Identity:

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public Startup(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    // Add (and configure) services to the container
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Global application settings (formerly known as Web.config) and other settings
        services.Configure<ApplicationSettings>(_config);

        // Application
        services.AddApplicationLayerServices();

        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options => 
        { 
            options.PageViewLocationFormats.Add("/Pages/Shared/Partials/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
            options.PageViewLocationFormats.Add("/Pages/Client/Partials/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
        });

        // Data store
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseOracle(_config.GetConnectionString("AppConnectionString")));

        // Security
        services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole<int>>(options => {
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();            
        
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            // Cookie settings
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);

            options.LoginPath = "/SignIn";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/FourZeroSomething";
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });

        services.AddAccessControlLayerServices();

        services.AddAuthorization(options => options.AddPolicies());

        services.Configure<RazorPagesOptions>(options => options.AddFoldersAuthorization());
    }

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }

        // Navigation
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();            
        app.UseStaticFiles();            
        app.UseRouting();
        
        // Security
        app.UseAuthentication();            
        app.UseAuthorization();

        // Endpoints
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapRazorPages());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As detailed in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies#what-should-a-handler-return), this behaviour is *by design*:

> If a handler calls `context.Succeed` or `context.Fail`, all other handlers are still called. This allows requirements to produce side effects, such as logging, which takes place even if another handler has successfully validated or failed a requirement. When set to `false`, the [`InvokeHandlersAfterFailure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationoptions.invokehandlersafterfailure#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authorization_AuthorizationOptions_InvokeHandlersAfterFailure) property short-circuits the execution of handlers when `context.Fail` is called. `InvokeHandlersAfterFailure` defaults to `true`, in which case all handlers are called.

If you'd rather not set the `InvokeHandlersAfterFailure` option, you can check the [`AuthorizationHandlerContext.HasFailed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationhandlercontext.hasfailed#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authorization_AuthorizationHandlerContext_HasFailed) property in your more specific handlers to see if it's `false` and return early. e.g.:

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RecordCreateRequirement requirement)
{
    if (context.HasFailed)
        return;

    // User ID
    int sessionUserId = int.Parse(_users.GetUserId(context.User));

    // ...
}
```